# Trouble converting DataTable to an Dictionary<int,int>

Tags: c#, linq

I am having trouble getting this chunk of code working.

```
DataTable dt = DataManager.GetSectionIdByEmail(test2PortalConnectionString, email);

Dictionary<int,int> clientViewIds = dt.Select(p => new {p.Key, p.Value })
     .AsEnumerable()
     .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.key as int, kvp => kvp.Value as int);
```

The error I am getting is: *Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type*

Resolution:  I had the AsEnumberable() in the wrong position in the statement, and I needed to handle the data rows.

```
Dictionary<int,int> clientViewIds = dt.AsEnumerable()
   .Select(dr => new { Key = dr["SectionID"], Value = dr["SectionTypeID"] })
   .ToDictionary(kvp =>(int)kvp.Key, kvp => (int)kvp.Value);
```

Comment: Are you `using System.Linq;`? Just checking

Comment: You can't do `as int` - `as` works with reference types, not value types. The correct syntax would be `(int)kvp.key` and `(int)kvp.Value`.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer `as` works with *nullable* types.  If it's a nullable value type (`Nullable<T>` is the only such type) then you can use `as`.  This is because `as` sets the value to `null` if it can't cast it, so if the type can't support a `null` assignment it can't work.

Comment: @djf  Yeah I am, that was one of the first things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DataTable` is not `IEnumerable`, so the [`Select()` method that you're actually invoking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) is entirely different; it takes a string.

There is an `AsEnumerable()` method which converts the `DataTable` to an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`.

But... `DataRow`s don't have `Key` and `Value` properties. So, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here. You can use column accessors to build the dictionary.

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Select(dr => new { Key = dr["Key"], Value = dr["Value"] })
    .ToDictionary(kvp => (int)kvp.Key, kvp => (int)kvp.Value);
```

Comment: I tweaked the answer to reflect what I ended up needing to us.  I could not use as Int and had to cast the values.

Comment: @DanSnell: Oh yes, that's right. `as` returns a `null` if the value doesn't match the type specified, and thus cannot be used with value types (like `int`) because they cannot take `null` as a value.

Answer (score 0):

*DataTable* does not support filtering with lambda, either provide a query or no parameter to get all the rows.

Then you can extract your data:

```
Dictionary<int,int> clientViewIds = dt.Select()
  .Select(r => new { Key = r["A"], Value=r["B"] })
  .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key as int, kvp => kvp.Value as int);
```